# Show skills used in each previous job on PDF export

Tags: feature-request, jobs

When employers are looking at a CV they like to see when the last time a prospective employee was using a particular skill set.

I know the PDF export of the CV has the Technical Skills section, however it would be nice if the skills used in each job could be reflected in the appropriate section.

The reason behind this is that even though I have Java in my 'Technical Skills' section, I may not have used it since a job I worked in 7 years ago, which would make my skills highly outdated and less relevant.

So, in short, is it possible to display the skills used at each previous job entry on the PDF export of the CV please?

Answer (score 1):

This would be moving away from the summary of qualifications that the Résumé is intended to be and moving more toward a full CV.  Additionally, a candidates interests (which are included on the résumé generator) should be the technologies that the employer weighs higher because they are the areas the candidate would like to work in.

As for your point about out dated and less relevant experience, there is also the case that a candidate would enjoy working for a specific company much more than they care about the technologies they would be using while working there, in which case the filter you suggest could be counter effective.

As a feature to the candidate, by preventing them from receiving contact from employers about positions they would not be interested in, this would only be useful if the employer is in fact using a filter such as "has professional experience in java in the last 3 years".  I personally think it's better to allow messages for positions you would never take (assuming it isn't an exceptionally large amount) rather than filter out the one job opportunity I wouldn't want to pass up.

Comment: A full CV is what we need in the UK

Comment: @IanRingrose: That is a separate feature request, which we would be happy to discuss in another post.